# Ajax response not working with Spring Webflow

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-webflow

I am trying to build an application using jQuery Ajax and Spring WebFlow. I can send value to controller but not getting whole page as response instead of specific `<script>`

**Making Ajax call using jquery**

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:country,
    url:$("#welcomeForm").attr("action")+"&_eventId_country&ajaxSource_country"+"&countryName="+country,
    success:function(states){
        console.log(states);
    }
});
```

**Flow.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<flow xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">
<var class="com.model.Welcome" name="welcome"/>
<on-start>
<evaluate expression="springWebFlow.countryList()" result="flowScope.countries"/>
</on-start>
<view-state id="welcome" model="welcome" redirect="false" view="/WEB-INF/views/welcome.jsp">
<transition on="country" bind="false">
<evaluate expression="springWebFlow.stateList(flowRequestContext)" result="flowScope.states" result-type=""/>
</transition>
<transition on="welcome" to="actionState1"/>
</view-state>
<end-state commit="false" id="actionState1" view="/WEB-INF/views/myDetails.jsp"/>
</flow>
```

**Controller:**

```
public @ResponseBody List<State> stateList(RequestControlContext context)  throws Exception {
    List<State> states= new ArrayList<State>() ;
    State stateName= new State();
    String countryName= context.getRequestParameters().get("countryName");
    if(countryName.equals("India")){
        stateName.setStateName("Delhi");
        states.add(stateName);
    }
     return states;
}
```

I do not want to use Spring JavaScript and not using Tiles. I can send request to controller but not able to get response (getting whole page) or show response in the page.

Comment: If you're getting a whole page as a response, it sounds like you're calling the wrong controller method. Have you tried debugging? Also what's `stateS`, some class variable? What is `states` for in both the JavaScript and Java code? On controller it's not saved anywhere and in the AJAX call you're alerting a variable not defined in the function.

Comment: can you post the full page response you get, and the posted URL?

Comment: it is just an html page

Answer (score 0):

In `WebMvcConfig`, ensure you have the `AjaxThymeLeafViewResolver` configured correctly. The bean name must be provided as **EXACTLY** `@Bean(name = "thymeleafViewResolver")`.

Why? Well I guess without naming the `AjaxThymeleafViewResolver` bean, the default bean name is just `ajaxThymeleafViewResolver` or something whereas spring only cares about a bean called `thymeleafViewResolver` similar to interfaces and concrete implementations. Eg you're saying to spring that we want to configure a `thymeleafViewResolver` to be an instance of `AjaxThymeleafViewResolver` to provide the specialized ajax handling for partial fragments.

Here is my config. This is a really subtle detail and its found in one of the thymeleaf spring mvc guides.

```
<bean id="thymeleafViewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.AjaxThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.FlowAjaxThymeleafView" />
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
</bean>
```

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#spring-webflow-integration

Mapping that xml into java using spring boot is given below.

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private WebFlowConfig webFlowConfig;

    @Autowired
    private SpringTemplateEngine springTemplateEngine;

    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping() {
        FlowHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new FlowHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setOrder(-1);
        handlerMapping.setFlowRegistry(webFlowConfig.flowRegistry());
        return handlerMapping;
    }

    @Bean
    public FlowHandlerAdapter flowHandlerAdapter() {
        FlowHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter = new FlowHandlerAdapter();
        handlerAdapter.setFlowExecutor(webFlowConfig.flowExecutor());
        handlerAdapter.setSaveOutputToFlashScopeOnRedirect(true);
        return handlerAdapter;
    }

    @Bean(name = "thymeleafViewResolver")
    public AjaxThymeleafViewResolver ajaxThymeleafViewResolver() {
        AjaxThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new AjaxThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(FlowAjaxThymeleafView.class);
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(springTemplateEngine);
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

The next thing you need to know is how understand `<render fragments=...>` since the documentation isn't clear IMO.

```
<view-state id="detail" view="bookingDetail" model="hotel">
    <transition on="updateData">
        <render fragments="hoteldata"/>
    </transition>
</view-state>
```

What does `hotelData` actually refer to? Look at the html thymeleaf markup.

```
<div th:fragment="hotelData">
  <h1 th:text="|The price is ${hotel.price}|">
</div>
```

Its saying that when you do an ajax post to the spring web flow endpoint `flowExecutionUrl` supplying `_eventId=updateData` as 1 of the serialized form fields etc, spring web flow will only send back the html markup for the `hotelData` fragment above with presumably a new hotel price which is made available through the model binding of `hotel`.

Pro tip:

Be very careful of the the validate and bind options. Its worth playing around with them if nothing is working for you up til this point. For example if you set bind to false, no form fields sent in the ajax request will be binded to the `hotel` model specified in the flow.xml view state as per above.

```
transition on="updateData" validate=true | false 
transition on="updateData" bind=true | false
```